# Материал по созданию надежной защиты для сервера и для mySQL

Tags: apache, защита, mysql, linux

В частности, меня интересуют популярные статьи или книги с наглядными примерами не позднее 2010 года по созданию защиты от хакеров для сервера Apache (конф. настройки и слаженная работа php) и БД mySQL. (Мне нужно будет применить знания на базе Linux Ubuntu 10.10).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если для Вас не критично "не позднее 2010 года", то покопайте новую защитную систему Suhosin под apache2. Появилась недавно (по крайней мере у меня на сервах после апдейта месяц назад), сам ещё конфиги не ковырял, но возможности и плюшки почитал, доставило. По словам великого и могучего дядьки Гугла там даже реализована каким-то чудодейственным образом защита от ДДОС атак. Так же очень понятные и обширные конфиги с огромным количеством плюх для защиты Вашего "индейца".